# Selenium did not accept my xpath expression

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I tried this xpath to retrieve a button

```
By addGhostButton = By.xpath("//button[@data-test-id=\"order\"]");
```

Selenium did not find it, I had this error *invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression*

Maybe the syntax is wrong ? any help please?

Comment: `By.xpath("//button[@data-test-id='order']")`

Comment: tried it, did not work

Comment: Are you sure the element is present ? Paste the dom here

Comment: <button class="sc-htpNat dNtmvw" data-test-id="order" type="submit"><span class="button-loader sc-ifAKCX hBcjPR"></span><span class="sc-bwzfXH dbjywt">Précommande maintenant</span></button>

Comment: There seems to be no issue with the given xpath, Just add a wait and it should hopefully work

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the complete error stack trace and the relevant HTML. However, the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you constructed is pretty much valid and legit. Hence you shouldn't see `invalid selector` error but *Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression* is pretty much possible.

The desired element looks to be a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button[data-test-id='order']")));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@data-test-id='order']")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xpath //button[Contains(text(),"Précommande maintenant")]`